# Cannot Get Image from Gallery in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-gallery

Cannot get image from gallery. Want to get images from gallery and display it. I am using [coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) library for displaying image.

```
var images by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Uri>()) }
    val galleryLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) {
            images = it
        }
    Column() {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                galleryLauncher.launch("image/*")
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Get images")
        }
        LazyColumn(content = {
            items(images.size){ uri ->
                AsyncImage(model = uri, contentDescription = null)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your are using the wrong `items` function in your `lazyColumn`.
the one you are using takes an `int` as a parametre and then it gives an `Int` to the body not a `uri`.:

```
    LazyColumn(content = {
        items(images.size){ Int->
            AsyncImage(model = Int, contentDescription = null)
        }
    })
```

you should use the other Items function from `androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`
and your code should something like this:

```
var images by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Uri>()) }
val galleryLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) {
        images = it
    }
Column() {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            galleryLauncher.launch("image/*")
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Get images")
    }
    LazyColumn(content = {
        items(images){ uri ->
            AsyncImage(model = uri, contentDescription = null)
        }
    })
}
```